# Change hotkey for pivot point

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-cursor

The default hotkey for median point is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>  and I want to change it for just <kbd>,</kbd>(comma).

How can I do that in Blender? I did not find this shortcut in preferences?

Comment: The shortcuts are easy to find, however one way to avoid dealing with different shortcuts for pivot point and alike is using Pie menus, then by pressing dot on the keyboard all of pivot points will appear in the viewport (actually default in 2.8)

Answer (score 1):

In the key preferences you can search by key-binding. For some reason these parameters names are "Context Set Enum", but I swapped the first two and it worked for me.
[image]